# RavenDB - Mixing Sharding with Multi-tenancy

Tags: ravendb, multi-tenant, sharding

Does anyone out there know if it is possible to use sharding with a multi-tenant RavenDB?

If you can, is there any major drawbacks or issues to be aware of?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, every tenant is consider to be a different database, so you can set things up that a sharded document store will talk to multiple databases, maybe on different servers.

Comment: Thanks Ayende. RavenDB Rocks!